# Spring Dependency Injection with anotaation in constructor with parameter

Tags: spring

I have below Spring class which I want to load with Spring DI. With default-constructor it's working as expected but can anyone tell me the annotation details and syntax with constructor with string arguments. This string arguments are run time.

I have tried with XML configuration "constrctor args" and working as expected.

```
    public someclass(String hostName, int port, String user, String password) {
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume your fields(hastName, port, user and password) are coming from properties file like for a server configuration.

```
@Component
public class SomeClass {

    @Autowired
    public someclass(@Value("${server.hostName}") String hostName, @Value("${server.port}") int port, @Value("${server.user}") String user, @Value("${server.passowrd}") String password ) {
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

If your params aren't static values, you would use programmatic way.
You need to autowire application context before you create instance of your bean.

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext ctx;
```

Then, create your bean instance and register it to application context,

```
BeanDefinitionRegistry registry = ((BeanDefinitionRegistry) ctx.getFactory());  

GenericBeanDefinition beanDefinition = new GenericBeanDefinition();  
beanDefinition.setBeanClass(SomeClass.class);  
beanDefinition.setLazyInit(false);  
beanDefinition.setAbstract(false);  
beanDefinition.setAutowireCandidate(true);  
beanDefinition.setScope("singleton"); // you should deal your scope.
ConstructorArgumentValues constructor = beanDefinition.getConstructorArgumentValues();
constructor.addIndexedArgumentValue(0, hostName);
constructor.addIndexedArgumentValue(1, port);
constructor.addIndexedArgumentValue(3, user);
constructor.addIndexedArgumentValue(4, password);

String beanName = "someclass"; // give a name to your bean

BeanComponentDefinition definition = new BeanComponentDefinition(beanDefinition, beanName);
BeanDefinitionReaderUtils.registerBeanDefinition(definition, registry);
```

Be careful while dealing your bean scope. You may use request or session scope according your structure.

At last, you can autowire SomeClass in other classes;

```
@Autowired
public SomeClass someClass;
```

Comment: Nope. It's not coming from properties file as this are not related to database. So, this things are dynamic in nature and will be passed from Java.

Comment: Humm that means you can't create this spring bean on the startup of your server. You can't use component scan. Therefore, you should create instance of this class on run time and register it to spring application context with programmatically. I can give more information about that if you want. But I believe you can't do it by annotation.

Comment: I think more information will be very much helpful for me. So, according to the comment only option I have is to do it manually with "new" operator.